# How to get a folder path dynamically?

Tags: java

I have a Business folder(e:\Business) in this folder I have compiled file  .I want use this folder in my main program  .My main Program is in the Main folder(e:\ProjectFile\Main)  .

I want get the path of Business folder dynamically  .I use this statment but didn't work :

```
String loadedClassPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"Business";

            File operatorFile = new File(loadedClassPath);
            URL operatorFilePath = operatorFile.toURL();          
            URL[] operatorFilePaths = new URL[]{operatorFilePath};
            ClassLoader operatorsClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(operatorFilePaths);
            Class[] operatorClass = new Class[]{ operatorsClassLoader.loadClass("Plus"), operatorsClassLoader.loadClass("Minus"),operatorsClassLoader.loadClass("Multiply") , operatorsClassLoader.loadClass("Divide") };
```

I think this part is not correct  :

```
String loadedClassPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"Business";
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Essentially, you can't, unless you intend to use the absolute path directly, there is very little to relate the "business" folder with your application folder.  A better solution would be place the business folder in a well known location, like `{user.home}\AppData\Local\{Your AppName}` on Windows o `{user.home}/Library/ApplicationSupport/{Your AppName}` on Mac

Comment: Another choice might be to define an environment variable which points to the folder location and use `System.getenv(...)` to retrieve it at runtime or pass it as an argument to your application

Comment: teacher said main program and Business should be in same drive . If I change the drive my program should work

Comment: FYI: Pretty sure you asked this yesterday, it's generally discouraged to "bump" posts

Comment: The place the "business" folder in a location relative to your code's execution, then you can use `user.dir` and add the relative portion of the path to it

Answer (score 2):

Since "e:\Business" is *entirely* unrelated to

- the location of your Java code
- your home directory (user.dir)
- any other well-know Windows or Java directory

you have to tell the program where/what it is.

Some options are:

1. Hard-code in Java program. *Not good*
2. Pass as argument to `main`.
3. Store in a property file that *is* located in one of the directories mentioned above.

There are likely more options, but option 3 is very common, option 2 is less common but might be better choice depending on circumstances, and option 1 is *highly* discouraged.

---

Note: When constructing a path/file name, use `new File(parent, child)`, or better yet, use the newer `Paths.get(first, more, ...)`.
"Newer" refers to Java 7, meaning since July 28, 2011, so not really that new any more.